# Is there a standard way to get the user config directory in python

Tags: python, cross-platform

I can get the home with `os.path.expanduser("~")` but is there a standard way to get the config directory? Like `~/.config` in most unices, or the value of `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` in (recent?) Linux and `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Roaming` in Windows), etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-platform method to obtain the user's configuration home directory in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26722607/cross-platform-method-to-obtain-the-users-configuration-home-directory-in-pytho)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loading a config file from operation system independent place in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250164/loading-a-config-file-from-operation-system-independent-place-in-python)

Comment: As of now, the best answer to this question is there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/63699709/3926735; though the next ones are good ones too.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can take advantage of python third party library <del>[appdirs](https://pypi.org/project/appdirs/)</del> [`platformdirs`](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/) which does all the heavy lifting for you across multiple platforms ( Windows, Linux & Mac )

Comment: The latest `appdirs` release as of the time of this comment is 7 Mar 2017.  The link in the answer currently goes to an older 2014 release.  I've submitted an edit so that the link always goes to the latest release.

Comment: P.S. The source code repository has [an active commit history](https://github.com/ActiveState/appdirs/commits/master) with commits from this year, so perhaps not abandoned as suggested in a comment above.

Comment: There seems to be a more active fork called platformdirs: https://github.com/platformdirs/platformdirs

Comment: @AlexPeters Looks like appdirs has officially been depreciated now.